# How do I turn (seq "foo") back into a string?

Tags: clojure

I'm exploring clojure and am puzzled.
What fills in the blank to make the following expression eval to true?

```
(= "foo" ___ (str (seq "foo")))
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use **apply** function:

```
user=> (apply str (seq "foo"))
"foo"
```

Comment: Do Clojure functions have a maximum arity (significantly lower than e.g. the max vector length)? E.g. if the string was really long here, then `apply` would try to call `str` with so many arguments (characters from the string) that the call would fail.

Answer (score 6):

Actually nothing can fill in the blank to make the expression (= "foo" *_* (str (seq "foo"))) eval to true because (str (seq "foo")) => "(\f \o \o)"  which is not equal to "foo" so we have an inequality already and a third item, no matter what value, to fill the blank cannot make the expression evaluate to true

If you meant to ask

```
(= "foo"
    (____ str (seq "foo")))
```

Then the answer would rightly be apply as answered by alex.

```
user> (doc apply)
-------------------------
clojure.core/apply
([f args* argseq])
  Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending args to argseq.
```

Apply takes a function (in this case str) and calls str with the args present in the seq

```
user> (seq "foo")
(\f \o \o)

user> (str \f \o \o)
"foo"
```

And oh, btw:

```
user> (= 1 1 1)
true

user> (= 1 2 1)
false
```

Comment: actually `(comp (partial apply str) read-string)` would work to fill the first blank :-)

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use the convient `clojure.string/join`

```
(require 'clojure.string)
(clojure.string/join (seq "foo"))
```

Will print `"foo"` as well. You could off course define your own `join` using the previously mentioned technique (to avoid write `(apply str seq)` all the time).